# Loop through Excel sheet and populate cells with data from other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to loop through a sheet with repeated items and fill in data in the next column with data from another sheet?  I've been searching for an answer for this but I can't find anything that matches this problem.  Any helpful advice or links to other answers would be very helpful!

I want to take the data from sheet 2 and add it to sheet 1.

For instance I was hoping to find a macro that would loop through cells B3:B13 on sheet 1 and fill C3:C13 with data from C3:C7 of sheet 2 based on the names of fruit on both sheets.

[image: Image of the two sheets]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
Sub FindWeight()

Dim lookUpSheet As Worksheet, updateSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToSearch As String
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer
Dim grams As Integer


Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set updateSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'get the number of the last row with data in sheet1 and in sheet2
lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'for every value in column A of Sheet1
For i = 1 To lastRowUpdate
     valueToSearch = updateSheet.Cells(i, 1)
     'look the value in column B of Sheet2
     For t = 1 To lastRowLookup
        'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next value
        If lookUpSheet.Cells(t, 1) = valueToSearch Then
            Set gram = lookUpSheet.Cells(t, 2)
            updateSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = gram
            Exit For
        End If
     Next t
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `VLOOKUP`,

Example:

```
= LOOKUP(4.19, A2:A6, B2:B6)
```

Looks up 4.19 in `column A`, and returns the value from `column B` that is in the same row.

this is a official [reference of microsoft](https://ttps://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)

Comment: Where would I add this function?  In cell C3 of sheet 1?

Comment: Yes, on sheet 1 you add the formula and refer to the table on sheet 2

Comment: There is no data in the A column

Comment: You need to think for yourself a bit, Jacob, most of the lookups work under `functionName(lookupValue, searchColumnOrRange,correspondingColumnOrRangeToShow [,maybeSomeOtherParameter])`. In your case, it'd be something like `VLOOKUP(B3,Sheet2!B3:C7,2,0)` with the 0 meaning exact match.